# After rebuilding WCF solution, IIS serves old XSD and WSDL files

Tags: c#, wcf, svn, wsdl, iis-7.5

I just rebuilt my WCF solution using VS2010 and uploaded it onto a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.5 on it. For some reason, even after cleaning up Temporary ASP.NET files, restarting the server - http://www.mysite.com/myservice?xsd=xsd1 (and all other XSD files) show old schemas.

As a result my generated WSDL is no use.

I've found this discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a9e48e3-25ec-4859-abe4-2b0a335b23ae/wcf-service-wont-update

But I've tried discussed above things, and it doesn't work. I have a feeling there's something very simple I'm missing here.

**Update:** After a while I found this post ([Update service reference not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665976/update-service-reference-not-working)), and when I moved my whole compiled WCF solution into a completely new AppDirectory, it broke with a "Could not load assembly xxxxx or one of its dependencies.
Then I checked my Fusion logs, and found this in one of the log files:

```
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my\path\to\lib.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: XXXXXX, Version=1.0.4983.31160, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x8007000b.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

**Workaround:** So I wouldn't consider this a solution, but after

1. I created a separate solution - self-hosted WCF service host,
2. Added all my references in there (my WCF service library was among them),
3. Built the self-hosted solution,
4. Ran the self-hosted EXE on the server, and ran the Design Time URL in the browser.
5. Was able to see correctly generated WSDL and XSD files!
6. Threw the necessary DLL's into the bin folder of my ASP.NET App Directory.
7. Refreshed my browser and saw the desired changes in the XSD!

My guess is that when I started the self-hosted service, and ran it in the browser, the new DLL's got stored in some temp ASP.NET directory that I'm not aware of. Then IIS used the directory to execute the DLL's.

I would appreciate if someone could explain how in the world this works, and what is the right way to do it.

**Solution:**

So after all my troubles, here is what happened:

- I use SVN for transmitting files onto the server.
- When I ran `svn up` on the server, there was a conflict that I resolved with the old files.
- Thus App Directory contained the old files, and the new files never made it there, because of the conflict.

Comment: There could be a ton of things going wrong, but the first question is: Are you absolutely sure you're connecting to the same server where you deployed it? e.g. Loopback in your machine config for testing purposes?

Comment: I know for sure, because I manually copied the files to the IIS application directory, where it was hosted before. Even messed with the web.config: turned off httpgetenabled then restored it. I have a feeling that there is some other cache being stored somewhere else...

Comment: You can try to set `Batch="false"`, which is an attribute of the `Compilation` tag in the web.config. That forces to create an individual cache per user instead of a gobal cache. You wouldn't want to leave it there though. It helped me with some nasty cahce persistence. I set it to false, made a couple of requests and removed it again. Also I didn't meant the deploying but connecting to it regarding the loopback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was caused by the old version of the main service assembly lying around near the new one in "bin" folder. They got there together because at one point I renamed it and it started deploying with a new name, but the old one stayed where it was, and that was giving me **intermittent** errors about missing contracts.